# Reference to adjacent columns of the same record for lookup values

Tags: database, ms-access, records

I am creating a Database with names and contact numbers.
Now there are three columns for 3 different Contact Numbers (like mobile, landline, etc).
Then I create another Column for the "Best Contact" ie which number should I try to dial first (out of the 3) to contact a record.

So I want to create a lookup on the Best Contact Field that drops down with the 3 Contact Numbers for that record.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the three columns of contact numbers are "mobile", "landline", and "cell", you can use something like this for the row source for the "best contact number" control.

```
select mobile 
from the_phone_numbers_table
where person_id_number = Forms!Your_form_name!person_id_number_control
union all
select landline
from the_phone_numbers_table
where person_id_number = Forms!Your_form_name!person_id_number_control
union all 
select cell
from the_phone_numbers_table
where person_id_number = Forms!Your_form_name!person_id_number_control
```

But you should also probably have a constraint in the table that guarantees the value of the "best contact" control equals one of those three numbers (one of those three columns), and no other number.

Comment: Actually, I didn't want to do this to a control on a form. I don't have a form. I want to do this in the table.